# Mixing objective-c and swift: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(target:action:)' for class

Tags: objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer, fatal-error

my code contains both objective-c and swift classes and so far, everything worked pretty well. however, i added a custom gesture recognizer that inherits from UIGestureRecognizer. My code compiles but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
    fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(target:action:)' for class
```

I assume that this error originates in the mix of objective-c and swift code but I have no clue how to solve it (besides rewriting everything in one of the languages). Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with code of your gesture recognizer.

Comment: Do you have any custom initializers in your view controller? If so, could you please try removing them and then run once.

Comment: It's just a matter of a misleading declaration of the method in UIKit. Ideally, it should have been declared as required and your runtime error would be replaced with a compile time one. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite normal, as

```
init(target target: AnyObject?,
     action action: Selector)
```

is exposed as a designated initializer in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/initWithTarget:action:).
However, it's strange that in the UIKit public sources it's declared as follows:

```
public init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) // designated initializer
```

Conclusion: even though it's not declared with the `required` keyword, you must implement it for your subclass. It may simply call the super's `init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector)`.
Good luck.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers. my subclass already had an init which looks as follows:

            `required init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector, threshold: CGFloat)
    {
        NSLog("Init is called")
        self.threshold = threshold

        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }`

Comment: Does it work now? If yes, please mark the answer accepted so that every one can see that it solves the problem.

Comment: no unfortunately it doesn't.  sorry that I didn't provide the information on my subclass at the beginning.

Comment: If you're stuck on that, feel free to drop me a line on the chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2799410/arthur-gevorkyan).

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i rewrote my code and the error is gone! very glad to receive so many helpful answers, i think i understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Extending to what Arthur mentioned, this is how Apple has defined it for `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` making it required for subclasses to implement.

> The NSCoding protocol requires that conforming types implement the
>   required initializer init(coder:). Classes that adopt NSCoding
>   directly must implement this method. Subclasses of classes that adopt
>   NSCoding that have one or more custom initializers or any properties
>   without initial values must also implement this method. Xcode provides
>   the following fix-it to serve as a placeholder implementation:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") 
}
```

Comment: That's a little bit off the record. Quite informative, though :)